# Default to class variables in a python class method?

Tags: python, class, default-value

I am writing a class method that I would like to use class variables if no other values are provided

```
def transform_point(self, x=self.x, y=self.y):
```

BUT... that doesn't seems to work:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I am getting the feeling there is a more clever way of doing this. What would you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use sentinel values, then replace those with the desired instance attributes. `None` is a good option:

```
def transform_point(self, x=None, y=None):
    if x is None:
        x = self.x
    if y is None:
        y = self.y
```

Note that the function signature is executed only *once*; you cannot use expressions for default values and expect those to change with each call to the function.

If you *have* to be able to set `x` or `y` to `None` then you need to use a different, unique singleton value as the default instead. Using an instance of `object()` is usually a great sentinel in that case:

```
_sentinel = object()

def transform_point(self, x=_sentinel, y=_sentinel):
    if x is _sentinel:
        x = self.x
    if y is _sentinel:
        y = self.y
```

and now you can call `.transform_point(None, None)` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
def transform_point(self, x=None, y=None):
    if x is None:
        x = self.x
    if y is None:
        y = self.y
```

etc

Comment: Please note that calling `transform_point(obj)` will cause all subsequent calls to `transform_point` to use the default arg `None` for `x` and `y`.